# Set pandas names after list items

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple xlsx files with data in it that i want to import to separate dataframes in Python.

Currently, i want to import a spreadsheet from 2014 september and 2014 october. The spreadsheets are in different folders for each year and the file names are as follows in the month_list variable. The desired dataframe names are "2014_09_sept_df" and "2014_10_okt_df"

```
month_list = ['09_sept', '10_okt']

df_string_list=[]
k = 0

for i in range(2014,2015):
    dirstring = 'C:/Users/folder/' + str(i)
    os.chdir(dirstring)

    for j in month_list:
        filestring = dirstring + '/' + j + '.xlsx'
        my_file = Path(filestring)            

        if my_file.exists():
            df_string_list.append(str(i) + '_' + j + '_df')
            df_string_list[k] = pd.read_excel(filestring)
            k+=1
```

My problem is that I've created the df_string_list list for holding the dataframe names, and when I want to name the dataframes with that item from the list, the dataframe gets put into the list with this command, instead of creating a dataframe:

```
df_string_list[k] = pd.read_excel(filestring)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was fixed. :) I can't use a list item, to name a dataframe, but the exec function and .format saved the day, like this:

```
if my_file.exists():
            exec('{} = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(filestring))'.format(j + '_' + str(i)))
```

Additional note: I also realized, that a dataframe name can't start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I suggest you use a dict and not a list:

```
df_string_list={}    #create an empty dict

for i in range(2014,2015):
    dirstring = 'C:/Users/folder/' + str(i)
    os.chdir(dirstring)

    for j in month_list:
        filestring = dirstring + '/' + j + '.xlsx'
        my_file = Path(filestring)            

        if my_file.exists():
            df_string_list[str(i) + '_' + j + '_df'] = pd.read_excel(filestring)
```

in this case, for example, `df_string_list['2014_09_sept_df']` contains the Dataframe from the right file.

To know all dataframe names loaded in your dict, use:

```
for dfname in df_string_list.keys():
  print(dfname)
  #print(df_string_list[dfname]    #uncomment to print the desired df
```

Comment: Great! This worked and created a dictionary, that contains my needed dataframes. How can I convert this dictionary to separate dataframes, as it was intended in the beginning?

Comment: you have the different keys in the dictionary which are the name of dataframe,for example df_string_list['2014_09_sept_df'] is one of dataframe in the dictionary. You have all keys and dataframe linked . If i missunderstand you explain precisely in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a list element as your dataframe name, you can do something like this at the end of your loop

```
globals()[df_string_list[k]] = pd.read_excel(filestring)
```